# How to set and limit page orientation in XAML or code?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, orientation

How to set and limit page orientation in XAML or code (for Windows Phone 8.1)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this...

```
void appBarButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Landscape;
   this.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
}
```